# Can I travel to France without a visa?

Tags: visas, france, uk-residents, gambian-citizens

My husband is British and I am a Gambian holding a Uk residents permit. We want to go to France for a holiday, can we go without me having a visa?

Comment: https://france-visas.gouv.fr/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa says that yes, you need a visa, unless you already have a Schengen visa or resident status.

Comment: @audionuma the logic on that page does not cover the case of family members of EU citizens who hold article 10 cards.  It is unlikely in this case, but possible, that OP is such a person.

Answer (score 3):

Those with a "Family member of an EU citizen" residence card do not need a Visa. Unfortunately because your husband is British your residency in the UK is normally a matter for UK national law not EU law which means your residence permit is probablly not* a "Family member of an EU citizen" residence permit.

So yes you probablly do need a Visa. However as you are travelling with your EU citizen spouse you benefit from special Visa rules. The Visa should be issued quickly and free of charge. In principle if you can demonstrate that you are a family member of an EU citizen you can even get the Visa on arrivial though this is generally not recommended.

Of course all of this is subject to change in the near future thanks to brexit.

https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm

* IIRC there are exceptions to this involving people who moved to the UK after living in other EU countries with their Non-EU spouses.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a Schengen Visa but the visa will be free of charge. The processing time for family members of EU citizens are generally processed a lot quicker and most countries in the Schengen Area only require certain documents for these family members.

**This information is subject to change due to Brexit.**

More information is available here: https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm