# Can I travel to France with my UK residence permit?

Tags: france, uk-residents, customs-and-immigration, democratic-republic-congo

I would like to travel to France to visit my family, however the Greek ambassador has my Congolese passport to stamp a visa because I am going on holiday over there. But in the meantime I would like to go to France with my UK residence permit with my British husband and kids. Do I need my passport to travel or I can use my UK residence permit card?

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects to the answer:

1) EU rules require non-EU family members to carry a valid passport https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm

2) Even if you had your passport, you need a Schengen visa for France unless your residence card is a "Family member of an EU citizen" residence card.
[Can I travel to France without a visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130167/can-i-travel-to-france-without-a-visa?r=SearchResults)

So no, you cannot travel without your passport and your residence card alone is not sufficient if it was issued under UK national rules.